# Regexes: Groups and repeated groups with \number

Tags: python, regex, string

I thought I understood the theory of how grouping with () worked in regex, but I am surprised by the behaviour I'm seeing in practice. I'd appreciate someone more knowledgeable explaining what's going on.

My assumptions are:
`'^.'` will match on any character at the start of the string. This one works as I expect.

`'^(.)'` is functionally the same, but with a grouping I can grab afterwards. This works as I expect.

`'^.+'` will match on at least one character at the start of the string, and go to the end (i.e. the whole string). This one works as I expect.

`^(.)\1'` should match the first 2 characters of the string if they are the same character (i.e. double letters. BUT when I run it, Python is telling me that nothing in the string matches. (test string: 'eefghijklmnop' - I thought it would match on 'ee')

`'^(.)+'` I THOUGHT should grab every character in the string in it's own group - except that when I run it, I'm only getting one character back, and it's the last one in the string?

Could someone please explain what's going on with the last 3 cases, and how to make it do what I want it to do - in this case, look for double letters at the start of the word?

TIA

Comment: Regarding your 3rd pattern, in your Python code, are you double escaping your back slashes or adding `r` to the beginning of the string (outside the quotes)?

Comment: Regarding your 4th pattern, you only have one capture group, and its contents are getting overwritten each time it matches, until it hits the end of the string.

Comment: @CAustin Thank you, that makes sense for pattern 4.
Turns out I did not have r in front of string for pattern 3. I'll have a play with it and see if it makes any more sense.

Comment: @CAustin The missing r was indeed the problem. Thank you again; I now understand what was going on!